# SP2010 workflow usage and limits

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

I have recently seen a commonly used workflow being placed in a 'starting' state where as before it was instantly run. I have added several new lists each with multiple workflows that trigger on change events. I fear I may have been carless when creating these workflows!
I have been told only 15 can run simultaneously. Is this true and if so are workflows that are in a 'Waiting' state affect this number and the resources on the FE sever? Am I also better merging 3 workflows in to 1 WF where possible? 
Also If I have hundreds of items in a list that have the same workflow 'In progress' due to them all waiting for 100 days does this have an effect on the speed of other workflows running?
Any general advice or best practices on WF usage and limits would be useful.
Thanks

Comment: Paused workflows do not count against that number, only workflows that are actively doing something are counted against that value.

Comment: If I amend a workflow that has many instances paused for months will the amendment's apply to these items?

Comment: I believe so, as long as you aren't pulling the data into a variable prior to pausing. When it resumes, it should see the updated value if you fetch it.

Comment: Is there somewhere on the server where I can see all running workflows so I can try and diagnose why so many of them take ages to move from 'Starting' to 'In Progress'?

Comment: Is the 15 limited to each front end server or is it a farm limit because I could add additional front end servers if it would increase the volume that could run simultaneously.

Comment: I think there is powershell to get all of them but I'm not positive. Perhaps in this case if the workflows are going to pause for so long, it could be shifted into a timer job.